# Run multiple Python programs on the same server (Ubuntu Server 12.04)

Tags: python, webserver

I am creating a webservice in Python and I have a question. I want to separate the user login user data. For this I am creating two different Python programs.

For example:
login.py -> localhost: 8080
userData.py -> localhost: 8081

My question is: how I can run these two programs on the same server? Is there a Python application server that is easy to use?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Both applications seem to run on different ports (8080 and 8081). So, what's exactly the problem ?

Comment: hm... You example will not work. You need a servers. Servers which handle web requests and which handle/reload/log python scripts. And don't forget about virtulenv. OR you have to do this work manually in your scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the webserver is embedded in the application, you may want to use some "watchdog" application to start/stop/restart.

Ubuntu uses [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

I like to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for this as well.

If the application supports some webserver integration protocol like FCGI or WSGI (python's standard), you may want to deploy it using a webserver. I've used apache [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) for a long time, lately I tend to use [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)+uwsgi. Apache is a fine webserver, but nginx+wsgi   scale better.

[update]

> Applications use Bottle + PyMongo (MongoDB) What do you recommend to be scalable?

First you should follow the advice on your framework documentation about deployment (bottle is not verbose [about this subject](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.10/tutorial.html#deployment), so I understand why you are asking).

B1 comment is right. You definitely want to place the database and application on distinct servers.

For maximum scalability with minimum fuzz you may want to look at some PasS provider like [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), [instructions here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python). This makes sense specially if you are a developer and not a system administrator.

Comment: Applications use Bottle + PyMongo (MongoDB)
What do you recommend to be scalable?

Comment: @mhergon any app on python are not scalable by desing. You can moove DB to separate server or nginx front-end proxy to another and speedup app. So no easy solutions for python but many succes stories like Disquss

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Ubuntu, using bash:

```
./login.py &
./userData.py &
```

This will run both scripts in the background.

If you want these scripts to keep on running after you close your shell:

```
at now < ./login.py
at now < ./userData.py
```

Comment: For this trick need `chmod u+x login.py userData.py`. But this didn't help handling requests for this need python code

Answer (score 0):

Tornado is a very easy to use application server. You can listen on different ports with different request handlers.

It is scalable and can handle thousands of connections. We use it to handle our console server. The simple hello world code really tells you all you need to know. I've added another HttpServer so that the single ioloop is handling requests on two different ports :

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpserver import HttpServer

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

class OtherHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Goodbye, world")

application1 = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])
application2 = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", OtherHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HttpServer(application1).listen(8080)
    HttpServer(application1).listen(8081)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

http://www.tornadoweb.org/